# Как откатить изменения сделанные после "git add" но до "git commit"?

Tags: git

В репозиторий когда-то был добавлен файл `src\test1.cpp` далее пойдет речь о трех состояниях файла:

1. На момент `git checkout` из удаленной ветки
2. Сделаны изменения и выполнена команда `git add src\test1.cpp`
3. Сделаны еще изменения в этом же `src\test1.cpp` файле, но `git add` не выполняли

Если сейчас запустить `git status`, то команда покажет, что проиндексированные изменения, но после были добавлены еще, которые не проиндексированы. В этих последних изменениях разработчик не больше нуждается и не хочет добавлять их в следующий комит.

Как разработчику откатить файл `src\test1.cpp` к состоянию 2 ?

Напомню о том, как работают некоторые команды:

- `git reset src\test1.cpp` - откат проиндексированных изменений, но они остаются файлововой системе. Другими словами как будто бы `git add` вообще никогда не делали, а это не то что надо!
- `git checkout src\test1.cpp` - откат проиндексированных и удаление изменений на файловой системе

После обеих этих команд проиндексированные изменения исчезают! А это не то что надо. Нужно их сохранить.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `git reset`: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-reset

Comment: как написали комментарий выше можно использовать команду `git reset`. Для конкретного файла команда выглядит следующим образом: `git reset src\test1.cpp`

Comment: Мне известно про команду `git reset src\test.cpp`, но она отработает не так как мне нужно. Она откатит в том числе уже проиндексированные изменения. А мне нужно их оставить! Убрать лишь то, что сделано после `git add`. Прошу прочитать вопрос внимательно

Comment: `git chekout <current brach>` вроде работает

Comment: @T0xee.n17 рекомендую почитать git book по-внимательнее. Она откатит проиндексированные изменения. А мой вопрос не откатить до комита, а откатить то что было после `git add` , т.е. оставить проиндексированное, но убрать локальное после него. ХЗ, как еще вопрос можно уточнить

Comment: не знаю есть ли для таких случаев отдельная команда. а что если если то что уже проиндексировано отправить в новую отдельную ветку, `git chekout <current brach>`, смержить с веткой с изменениями и удалить новую ветку?

Comment: @bilal так мой же вопрос не в том как сделать отдельную ветку! ;) Мой вопрос в другом. В том: как убрать изменения после `git add`. Меня именно это интересует!

Comment: `git restore src\test1.cpp`. Обратите внимание на вывод команды `git status` там все написано

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Да. Это то что надо Можете оформить в виде нормального ответа и я отмечу его решением?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужна команда `git restore`:

```
git restore src\test1.cpp
```

Она отменяет изменения в локальной копии, которые еще не добавлены в индекс.

Обратите внимание, что `git status` подсказывает, какие команды что делают в данной ситуации. В этом случае полезна часть про `to discard changes in working directory`:

```
On branch my-branch
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/my-branch' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified: src/test1.cpp

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified: src/test1.cpp
```